# How can I achieve a uwsgi_pass with openresty's Lua plugin?

Tags: lua, uwsgi, openresty

I need to perform some semi-complex logic on an incoming request that matches a particular location.  In short, for all urls conforming to `location ~* "^/([0-9a-f]{8}-([0-9a-f]{4}-){3}[0-9a-f]{12})/?$"`, the following needs to take place:

1. Check if admin cookie is present.  If so:

   - Rewrite URL (`/<uuid>` -> `/mod/<uuid>`)
   - Perform `uwsgi_pass`
2. Else:

   - Perform lookup in postgres for an entry matching the UUID
   - Search the entry for a usable redirect URL
   - Redirect the client to the selected URL

All of this is fairly straightforward using `content_by_lua_block`, except for the `uwsgi_pass` bit; Google has proven most unhelpful in this endeavor...

**How can I perform a `uwsgi_pass` in a `content_by_lua_block`**?

Comment: Why do you need the `uwsgi_pass` in the content_by_lua? based on your requirement 1 and 2 flows seem mutually exclusive. 

Flow 2: postgres lookup and produce a redirect. Moreover, it seems that a rewrite_by_lua phase handler will be more appropriate.

Comment: @danielgpm, It's not required *per se*, I just assumed it would be easier to implement all of this logic in a single `content_by_lua` block.  Could you please elaborate on your proposed solution?  I'd be happy to accept it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although a little late, here is:

```
location ~* "^/([0-9a-f]{8}-([0-9a-f]{4}-){3}[0-9a-f]{12})$" {
          set $uuid $1;                  
          rewrite_by_lua ' 
            local new_url
            if (ngx.var.cookie_admin) then
              new_url = "/modif/" .. ngx.var.uuid                
            else               
              --Get the url from DB using uuid
              local res = ngx.location.capture("/url/" .. ngx.var.uuid);                   
              if (res.status == 200 and res.body)  then 
                new_url = tostring(res.body) --change the uri to the one from DB                  
              else 
                return ngx.exec("@notfound") -- Fallback locaton if no url found in DB
              end               
            end
            ngx.req.set_uri(new_url) -- rewrite uri to new one
          ';
          echo $uri; #test
          #uwsgi_pass upstream_server;
    }
```

It worked fine, with this two locations for testing:

```
location ~ "^/url/(.+)$" {
  internal;      
  set $uuid $1;
  #return 410; # test Uncomment to test @notfound
  echo "/url/from/db/$uuid"; #test   

  #assuming you have postgre module
  #postgres_pass     database;
  #rds_json          on;
  #postgres_query    HEAD GET  "SELECT url FROM your_table WHERE uuid='$uuid'";
  #postgres_rewrite  HEAD GET  no_rows 410;
}

location @notfound {
  echo "Ping!  You got here because you have no cookies!";
}
```

Comment: Not at all too late!  Your timing is actually great, as I was just diving back into this.  Thanks!